# Suspicious cast on item where both collections are the same?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, collections, casting

I am getting a suspicious cast warning from Re-Sharper and subsequently a null object on compile time for my cast.

Here is the controller code which gets the collection through a service class:

```
var serviceResult = CatLookupService.CatLookupService.GetCatMakes(CatTypeCode);

if (!serviceResult.OperationSuccess || serviceResult.ServiceObject == null ||
    !serviceResult.ServiceObject.Any())
    return Json(new { Success = false, ErrorMessage = TextResources.InvalidCat });

serviceResult.ServiceObject = (ICollection<KittyCatMake>)viewModel.EditCampaignCatMakeViewModels;
```

Here is the serviceResult Collection class (`ICollection<KittyCatMake>`):

```
  public class KittyCatMake
  {
    public string CatbookCode { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
  }
}
```

and finally here is my EditCampaignCatMakeViewModels Collection class:

```
public class EditCampaignCatMakeViewModel
{
    public string CatBookCode { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool Checked { get; set; }

    public ICollection<EditCampaignCatModelViewModel> EditCampaignCatModelViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

also the idea here is to get the collection to match the View Model so I can create a bunch of partial views for each Collection object, get some data from the user then pass it back to the db. So at the moment the main view model is holding a collection of partial view models as such:

```
public class EditCampaignVehicleDetailsViewModel
    {
         public ICollection<EditCampaignVehicleMakeViewModel> EditCampaignVehicleMakeViewModels { get; set; }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is the suspicious cast?: `(ICollection<KittyCatMake>)viewModel.EditCampaignCatMakeViewModels` I'm surprised that even compiles, considering you're casting an `ICollection<EditCampaignCatModelViewModel>` to a `ICollection<KittyCatMake>` and there is no relationship between your `KittyCatMake` and `EditCampaignCatMakeViewModel` classes.

Comment: Basically I just want to copy the CatbookCode and Description from the KittyCatMake collection and create a new EditCampaignCatModelViewModel with the CatBookCode and Description from the KittyCatMake, any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You can use `AutoMapper` library to map one type to another and easily copy/convert data from one list to another. Check [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/using-automapper-in-c-sharp)